# Deploying branches and maintaining configs in VS2010 / VSOnline

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs, clickonce, azure-devops

I'm trying to get one of our internal c# click once applications into VSOnline for source control to allow access for an external developer.

I think I've got it set up and working in the Source Control Editor, but am having trouble working through how to actually use the setup day to day.

I've got some git experience but zero TFS experience, but went with the TFS option as I thought it's more likely developers are familiar with it than git.

What I'm trying to achieve is 3 branches; Main/Trunk, Dev and Release and be able to deploy at least Release and Main. Release is for external clients, Main for internal clients.

At the moment my Source Control Explorer looks like;

```
DefaultCollection
-->Name of project
---->(Branch icon) Dev (created as a Branch from Main)
---->(Branch icon) Main
---->(Branch icon) Release (created as a Branch from Main)
```

2 things;

1. In terms of use I'm not really sure how to swap between the branches for coding / making changes? Do I just open the solution file for the branch I want to work on then save all changes as I go, then commit that as a changeset? Or is it a matter of manually checking the file out, working on it, then checking it back in again?
2. Given it's a ClickOnce app; each branch is deployed to a different IIS site, meaning diff app identies, paths and settings. Am I right in using branches for this or is there a better way? I'm worried about someone committing the wrong file and causing a mandatory uninstall/reinstall of the app.

Any pointers / docco greatly appreciated; just note I'm using VS2010.

Thanks,
Liam

Comment: You can give me this [task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852766/parse-xml-nodes-to-csv-with-ruby-nokogiri/21852822#21852822) personally, if you want. If you want you can email me. The email is written in my profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How do I swap between branches

If you're used to GIT than the 'heavy weight' branching in TFVC can be a bit confusing. There is no real "Switching between branches" as you've encountered. You map a branch to a local folder and by opening the files there you're "working on that branch".

As Lee points out you can create separate workspaces for each branch, which will isolate the work areas for each. If you're using a Local Workspace, each workspace gets its own "/tf$" folder, the TFVC equivalent of the "/.git" folder.

There's a couple of documents on MSDN that explain this in a little more detail:

- [Set up TFVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181384.aspx)
- [Create one or more workspaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx)
- [Optimize your workspaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181378.aspx)

### How do I check in

A changeset in TFVC is the equivalent of a commit in Git, it's a logical set of changed files that is committed/pushed as a whole, or not at all. But just as in Git, you can commit all the changes to your local work area at once, or you can exclude certain changes from the first commit and stick those in a second.

In TFVC you'd normally try to commit a logical set of files that fixed the bug, achieved some goal etc. Though it's still possible to check-out/check-in files individually, chances are much higher that you'll actually cause the sources in the main repository to be in an inconsistent state that way.

See

- [What is a Changeset](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/korbyp/archive/2004/07/15/184442.aspx)
- [Check in your work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181407.aspx)
- [Shelving your work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx)

### As for your second question

Depending on how far you'd want to go, you could setup Team Build to actually build the application and to take the configuration from a specific location during the build process. That way you wouldn't have to store the configuration for your production environment with the development settings. Configuration files can contain sensitive information, you might not want to have them in Source Control, except for the development versions.

You can also store the config files in a special folder in each branch and make sure that each time you merge them, they're updated accordingly.

And you can, as Lee mentions, look into [Config Transaformations](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5). which apply some XSLT to your config file in the build process. That way you can have multiple config files stored in each branch and the selection of your "Configuration" in Visual Studio will define what the final config looks like.

See:

- [Tricks with app.config files and click once](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/09/tricks-with-app-config-and-clickonce-deployment-saurabh-bhatia.aspx)
- [The _PublishedApplication Nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PublishedApplications/)
- [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)

Comment: Fantastic - thank you for the links. Re having the different workspaces with the branches; do I still then merge the changesets back across the workspaces to a main branch?

Answer (score 1):

> In terms of use I'm not really sure how to swap between the branches for coding / making changes?

I recommend creating separate workspaces for each branch. This way you won't accidentally check in release code when you are trying to check in dev code. Also, when you want to switch which branch of code you are working on, you switch your workspace. This should keep things "cleaner" and easier to work with.

> Do I just open the solution file for the branch I want to work on then save all changes as I go, then commit that as a changeset? Or is it a matter of manually checking the file out, working on it, then checking it back in again?

You shouldn't have to manually check it out. If I remember correctly, it will default to auto check out when you start to make changes. You can check code in however big of chunks as you want. But make sure if you are checking in changes to ClassA.cs that reference needed changes in ClassB.cs, you check that in as well. You don't want to leave the source code in a broken state for the other developers.

If you start working on something and have to suspend that work to do some other task that rose in importance, [shelve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) your work instead of letting your workspace get cluttered up with half done work that makes it difficult to manage check ins.

> Given it's a ClickOnce app; each branch is deployed to a different IIS site, meaning diff app identies, paths and settings. Am I right in using branches for this or is there a better way?

I'd look into using [web.config transformations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx) for this. You'll still want multiple branches but to separate tested/completed/developing code from each other.

Comment: Ok, will look into the transformations for the configs. For the opening of files; this is incredibly basic but; do I open VS then open the workspace folder, then pick the .sln file or is it a matter of using the source code explorer to browse to where I want to make changes?

Comment: I use the source control explorer in VS. Select the workspace you want to work in using the combobox and then open the appropriate .sln file. When merging branches, you select the target workspace/branch using the combobox in the source control explorer, right click the source workspace/branch and choose to merge. After working out any merge conflicts, check your code in using the pending changes window.

Comment: I started out using one big workspace but found it's easier to stay organized if I keep them separate. The pending changes window won't be cluttered up with files from all different branches.