# How to parse XML nodes to CSV with Ruby and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, csv, nokogiri

I have an XML file:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Offers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ssc.channeladvisor.com/files/cageneric.xsd">
  <Offer>
   <Model><![CDATA[11016001]]></Model>
   <Manufacturer><![CDATA[Crocs, Inc.]]></Manufacturer>
   <ManufacturerModel><![CDATA[11016-001]]></ManufacturerModel>
   ...lots more nodes
   <Custom6><![CDATA[<li>Bold midsole stripe for a sporty look.</li>
    <li>Odor-resistant, easy to clean, and quick to dry.</li>
    <li>Ventilation ports for enhanced breathability.</li>
    <li>Lightweight, non-marking soles.</li>
    <li>Water-friendly and buoyant; weighs only ounces.</li>
    <li>Fully molded Croslite&trade; material for lightweight cushioning and comfort.</li>
    <li>Heel strap swings back for snug fit, forward for wear as a clog.</li>]]></Custom6>
  </Offer>
....lots lots more <Offer> entries
</Offers>
```

I want to parse each instance of 'Offer' into its own row in a CSV file:

```
require 'csv'
require 'nokogiri'

file = File.read('input.xml')
doc = Nokogiri::XML(file)
a = []
csv = CSV.open('output.csv', 'wb') 

doc.css('Offer').each do |node|
    a.push << node.content.split
end

a.each { |a| csv << a }
```

This runs nicely except I'm splitting on whitespace rather than each element of the Offer node so every word is going into its own column in the CSV file.

Is there a way to pick up the content of each node and how do I use the node names as headers in the CSV file?

Comment: show us the expected csv file content, and what you are now getting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This assumes that each `Offer` element always has the same child nodes (though they can be empty):

```
CSV.open('output.csv', 'wb') do |csv|
  doc.search('Offer').each do |x|
    csv << x.search('*').map(&:text)
  end
end
```

And to get headers (from the first `Offer` element):

```
CSV.open('output.csv', 'wb') do |csv|
  csv << doc.at('Offer').search('*').map(&:name)
  doc.search('Offer').each do |x|
    csv << x.search('*').map(&:text)
  end
end
```

`search` and `at` are Nokogiri functions that can take either XPath or CSS selector strings. `at` will return the first occurrence of an element; `search` will provide an array of matching elements (or an empty array if no matches are found). The `*` in this case will select all nodes that are direct children of the current node.

Both `name` and `text` are also Nokogiri functions (for an element). `name` provides the element's name; `text` provides the text or CDATA content of a node.

Comment: Thanks kardeiz; that works perfectly. To confirm my understanding; 'at' means at first instance of 'Offer', then search * finds all nodes under 'Offer'. map/&name then gets node names (so name belongs to nokogiri in this instance?, but map belongs to csv library?)

Comment: I've added a little information about the various functions to my answer. You are correct in your understanding, except that `map` here is not a CSV function; the result of `search` is a node set that acts like a Ruby `array`, so you can do the normal map on its elements. The only CSV functions are `open` and the `<<` calls, which push a new row to the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and modify it to push into your CSV:

```
doc.css('Offer').first.elements.each do |n|
  puts "#{n.name}: #{n.content}"
end
```