# Ruby XML to CSV with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, csv, nokogiri

I'm very new to ruby and to programming at all. I'm trying to export XML to CSV using Ruby and nokogiri. My code:

```
require 'csv'
require 'nokogiri'

file = File.read('example.xml')
doc = Nokogiri::XML(file)
a = []
csv = CSV.open('output.csv', 'wb') 

CSV.open('output.csv', 'wb') do |csv|
    csv << doc.at('Start').search('*').map(&:name)
    doc.search('Start').each do |x|
      csv << x.search('*').map(&:text)
    end
  end
```

XML I want to convert:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Start>
        <Value1>2018-10-15</Value1>
        <Value2>2018-11-17</Value2>
        <Value3>
            <ID type="Value3_ID">XXX1</ID>
        </Value3>
        <Value4>
            <ID type="Value4_ID">XXX2</ID>
        </Value4>
        <Value5>
            <ID type="Value5_ID">XXX3</ID>
        </Value5>
        <Value6.1>
            <Value6.2>
                <ID type="Value6.2_ID">XXX4</ID>
            </Value6.2>
            <Value6.3>XXX5</Value6.3>
            <Value6.4>XXX6</Value6.4>
            <Value6.5>
                <ID type="Value6.5_ID">XXX7</ID>
            </Value6.5>
            <Value6.6>XXX8</Value6.6>
            <Value6.7>XXX9</Value6.7>
        </Value6.1>
        <Value6.1>
            <Value6.2>
                <ID type="Value6.2_ID">XXX10</ID>
            </Value6.2>
            <SValue6.3>XXX11</SValue6.3>
            <Value6.5>
                <ID type="Value6.5_ID">XXX12</ID>
            </Value6.5>
        </Value6.1>
    </Start>
</root>
```

Sorry for very basic question. The most important thing for me is that the xml will be converted automatically cause I have a lot of different XMLs so I can't list all the nodes I need. 
+ it would be great to not have this empty nodes....

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Just check some existing examples:

- https://bits.ashleyblewer.com/blog/2016/09/21/lorena-parsing-xml-into-csv-with-ruby/
- https://gist.github.com/bxt/454bb3b6ad7d2fdba0a5b1efb9b45d86
- [Parse XML nodes to CSV with Ruby/Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852766/parse-xml-nodes-to-csv-with-ruby-nokogiri)